# Transform '1-1-1 through 1-10-1' to ten values of '1-1-1', '1-2-1',... '1-10-1'

Tags: regex, r

I have a dataframe like below:

```
ID     
1-1-1, 1-2-1
2-1-1
3-1-1 through 3-5-1
```

I am looking to transform the dataframe to

```
ID    
1-1-1
1-2-1
2-1-1
3-1-1
3-2-1
3-3-1
3-4-1
3-5-1
```

For first row in the first dataframe, I think melt can do the job. But for third row, I think I should somehow substitute the 'through' to IDs in between. I tried some regular expression but did not find a good way to do so.

Following Question:

what if there is another column and I want to match them?

```
NewColumn  ID
A          1-1-1, 1-2-1
B          2-1-1
C          3-1-1 through 3-5-1
```

to

```
NewColumn ID
A         1-1-1
A         1-2-1
B         2-1-1
C         3-1-1
C         3-2-1
C         3-3-1
C         3-4-1
C         3-5-1
```

first digid in ID could be the same for multiple New Columns items.

Comment: Thanks akrun! That is quick and poswerful. And how do I sub 'through' in '3-1-1 through 3-5-1' to IDs in between?

Comment: First I thought that it was a duplicate.  But, then I realized your question is good.

Comment: @akrun it's not yet another `cSplit` dupe?

Comment: No, I closed it earlier, but seems more work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do this using `cSplit` from `splitstackshape` and `data.table` approaches after we replace the `through` with `,` using `sub`.

Using regex `sub`, we match if there is zero or more space (`\\s*`) followed by `through` followed by zero or more space (`\\s*`) and replace that it with `,`  for the 'ID' column.

```
df1$ID <- sub('\\s*through\\s*', ', ', df1$ID)
```

Now we use `cSplit` to split the 'ID' column using delimiter as `,`  and specifying the direction as 'long'.  The output is still non-numeric.  So, if we wanted to make a sequence, it is better to split that into 'numeric'.  We do a second `cSplit` using `-` as delimiter and the default direction as 'wide'.  We get three columns.  Now, we can use the `data.table` approaches.  We can group by the 'ID_1' and 'ID_3' columns and check `if` the number of elements (`.N`) in the group is `>1` or not.  If there are multiple elements, we get the sequence of the first and last element (here there is only two elements, so 1st and 2nd i.e. of the ID_2 column, and finally `paste` the three columns together and create a 'data.frame'.

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(data.table)

 ID <- cSplit(cSplit(df1, 'ID', ', ', 'long'), 'ID', '-', type.convert=TRUE)[, 
       list(ID_2=if(.N>1) ID_2[1]:ID_2[2] else ID_2), by = .(ID_1, ID_3)
        ][, paste(ID_1, ID_2, ID_3, sep="-")]
 d1 <- data.frame(ID, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 d1
#ID
#1 1-1-1
#2 1-2-1
#3 2-1-1
#4 3-1-1
#5 3-2-1
#6 3-3-1
#7 3-4-1
#8 3-5-1
```

---

For easier understanding, the code can be split into chunks.  We split based on the ', ' to create a 'long' format

```
 cLong <- cSplit(df1, 'ID', ', ', 'long')
```

In the next step, it is split on '-' and we use the option `type.convert=TRUE` to convert the columns to their respective classes.

```
 cLong1 <- cSplit(cLong, 'ID', '-', type.convert=TRUE)
```

Now, we use `data.table` approach as the output from `cSplit` is already a 'data.table'

```
 DT1 <- cLong1[, list(ID_2=if(.N>1) 
                            ID_2[1]:ID_2[2] 
                            else ID_2),
                                 by = .(ID_1, ID_3)]
```

We paste the columns together

```
 ID <- do.call(paste, c(DT1[,c(1,3,2), with=FALSE], sep='-'))
```

and create a 'data.frame'

```
 data.frame(ID)
```

#### Update

For the follow up question, we only need to change in the `cSplit` step.  We can add 'NewColumn' as the grouping variable.

```
df1$ID <- sub('\\s*through\\s*', ', ', df1$ID)

cSplit(cSplit(df1, 'ID', ', ', 'long'), 'ID', '-',
    type.convert=TRUE)[,  list(ID_2=if(.N>1) ID_2[1]:ID_2[2] else ID_2),
    by = .(NewColumn, ID_1, ID_3)
    ][,list(ID=paste(ID_1, ID_2, ID_3, sep="-")) ,.(NewColumn)]
#   NewColumn    ID
#1:         A 1-1-1
#2:         A 1-2-1
#3:         B 2-1-1
#4:         C 3-1-1
#5:         C 3-2-1
#6:         C 3-3-1
#7:         C 3-4-1
#8:         C 3-5-1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("1-1-1, 1-2-1", "2-1-1",
"3-1-1 through 3-5-1")), .Names = "ID", class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA, -3L))
#newdata
df1 <- structure(list(NewColumn = c("A", "B", "C"),
ID = c("1-1-1, 1-2-1", 
"2-1-1", "3-1-1 through 3-5-1")), .Names = c("NewColumn", "ID"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Hi akrun, thanks for your fast response! It is a good method that splitting each ID into ID2 and ID3, which makes a lot sense both in term of R scripting and the actually ID naming. However when I try your one line code, an error raises as  `Error in as.data.table.matrix(X[[x]]) : 
  4 arguments passed to .Internal(nchar) which requires 3`

Comment: @Hanfu Can you try the step by step code to know where the error occured.  I am using the devel version of data.table i.e. v1.9.5

Comment: I use data.table 1.9.4. It failed at `R> cLong1 <- cSplit(cLong, 'ID', '-', type.convert=TRUE)
Error in as.data.table.matrix(X[[x]]) : 
  4 arguments passed to .Internal(nchar) which requires 3`

Comment: @Hanfu I am using `splitstackshape_1.4.2` and `data.table_1.9.5`.  Are you using the same example to get this error?

Comment: i do use the exact example I stated in the question. I use splitstackshape_1.4.2 and data.table_1.9.4. And error sticks when using data.table_1.9.5

Comment: @Hanfu That is strange as I am getting the result without any errors